# Compiler Error Message: CS0118: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings' is a 'property' but is used like a 'method'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Compiler Error Message: CS0118: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings' is a 'property' but is used like a 'method'

```
<add key="ObjConn" value="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=OMembers;PWD=OMembers;Initial Catalog=Db;Data Source=""/>

 strconnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ObjConn");
          sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strconnection);
```

Answer (score 7):

in `C#`, do this:

```
strconnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ObjConn"];
sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strconnection);
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're working in C#? You need to access it using index operator:

```
strconnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ObjConn"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to define connection strings in the connection strings section as so:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add 
      name="ObjConn" 
      connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
   />
</connectionStrings>
```

And instantiate you SqlConnection like this:

```
strconnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ObjConn"].ConnectionString;
sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strconnection);
```